# Nuxt - Node error when I want to import some packages

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I use Nuxt, and sometimes, when I want to use some npm packages, I have this error:

```
SyntaxError
Unexpected token '<'
```

The stack:

```
vm.js:102:7
new Script
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10
Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32
Module.load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14
Module._load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19
Module.require
webpack:/external "vue-typeahead-bootstrap":1:
Object.vue-typeahead-bootstrap
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
pages/account/tabs/addresses.js:693:81
Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/address/form/country.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
webpack/bootstrap:25:
```

I have this error for example on this package: `vue-typeahead-bootstrap`

If I import the package:

```
import VueTypeaheadBootstrap from ['vue-typeahead-bootstrap'](https://github.com/mattzollinhofer/vue-typeahead-bootstrap)

export default {
  components: { VueTypeaheadBootstrap },
}
```

It throws the error.

Is it because the package is not supported or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to transpile it. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#transpile

Add the package name like this

```js
{
  build: {
    transpile: [
      ({ isServer }) => 'vue-typeahead-bootstrap'
    ]
  }
}
```

As answered here: https://github.com/mattzollinhofer/vue-typeahead-bootstrap/issues/19#issuecomment-645510809

Comment: Ok it seems to do the job ! thanks, I will read more about transpiling

Comment: @VincentDecaux transpiling is when you make some code, like ES6 compatible with commonJS code. Here, this package was probably only working with ES6, hence why we need to ask it to be transpiled.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I am understanding it. But, dunno if nuxt / node have some cache, because it worked at one moment, then not anymore